# Review screen not opening with new screen

Tags: gerrit

This is rather strange problem. When I click a file for side-by-side review, this message comes up:

```
Code Review - Error
The page you requested was not found, or you do not have permission to view this page.
```

However, when I change my view to "Old Screen" using Setting->Preferences, everything just works fine. What's with this? Has anyone encountered this kind of a situation before? I am using ssh (not http) for sending reviews, etc.